# MySQL: оптимизация скрипта поиска минимального и максимального значений в массиве

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация

Имею задачу - поиск и вывод *мин* и *макс* значений из двух столбцов таблицы.

Пример значений ячеек таблицы *TABLE*:

```
ID |S-MIN|S_MAX
0  |10   |31
1  |4    |8
2  |6    |0
```

Искать *мин* и *макс* надо только среди значений больше нуля.

Я смог изобразить только такое решение:

### Скрипт

```
//ищу минимум в первом столбце
$smin=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `S_MIN`  FROM `table` ORDER BY `S_MIN` ASC limit 1"));
//ищу максимум в первом столбце
$sminmax=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `S_MIN`  FROM `table` ORDER BY `S_MIN` DESC limit 1"));
//ищу максимум во втором столбце
$smax=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query ("SELECT `S_MAX`  FROM `table` ORDER BY `S_MAX` DESC limit 1"));
//if нужен на случай, если максимальное значение таблицы будет лежать в первом столбце
if ($smax < $sminmax)
echo "Минимум=".$smin[0].", максимум=".$sminmax[0]."";
else
echo "Минимум=".$smin[0].", максимум=".$smax[0]."" ;
```

Подумав, что 3 запроса в БД не есть гуд, начал двигаться в сторону оптимизации, да так и не придвинулся до конца.

Примерно так я дошел до такого состояния:

### Оптимизация

```
//извлекаем все значения талицы в массив
$query = "SELECT `S_MIN`, `S_MAX`  FROM `table`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
//сортируем все значения в массиве (при этом, как я понял происходит переиндексация)
sort ($array);
//и удаляем первый элемент массива, который скорее всего ноль.
//сейчас понял, что нельзя просто так удалять первый элемент, ведь в таблице может и не быть нулей
unset($array[0]);
//дальше все просто
$smin = min($array);
$smax = max($array);
echo "Минимум=".$smin[0].", максимум=".$smax[0]."";
```

Подскажите, где ошибка в моем варианте оптимизации. И вообще стоит ли игра свеч?

Повторюсь, первый скрипт рабочий.

Ах, и да, я не озадачиваюсь поиском минимума во втором столбце, т.к. структура данных такова, что его там быть не может по определению.

Comment: А как же функции min и max в самом mysql?

Comment: Да, я в курсе. С этими функциями я не смог сдюжить, в плане укладки их в один sql запрос. А вопрос именно в минимизации обращений к БД.

Comment: а что именно выдаёт первый скрипт на приведённых вами данных?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну, сейчас посчитаем =) smin=4, sminmax=10, smax=31; На печати будет минмиум=4, максимум=31

Comment: ваш ответ совпадает с предложенным мною запросом. значит, я угадал верно.

Comment: так. кажется, немного разобрался в вашем коде. вам нужен минимум по значениям из **обоих** столбцов и **максимум** — также по значениям из обоих столбцов. правильно?

Answer (score 1):

примерно такой запрос вам нужен, если я всё понял правильно.

**обновление**

кажется, вам требуется несколько иное: выбрать максимальное значение в **любом** из двух столбцов, и минимальное значение в любом из тех же двух столбцов.

это реализовано ниже: запрос номер два — с использованием вспомогательных *view*, запрос номер три — без них.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f015/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int, s_min int, s_max int);

insert into t values
   (0, 10, 31)
  ,(1, 4, 8)
  ,(2, 6, 0)
  ,(3, -1, 50)
  ,(4, 35, -2)
  ,(5, 7, 3)
;

create view v1 as
  select min(s_min) as r
  from t
  where s_min >0;

create view v2 as
  select min(s_max) as r
  from t
  where s_max >0;

create view v3 as
  select max(s_min) as r
  from t
  where s_min >0;

create view v4 as
  select max(s_max) as r
  from t
  where s_max >0;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select min(s_min) as min, max(s_max) as max
from t
where s_min > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f015/1/0)**:

```
| min | max |
|-----|-----|
|   4 |  31 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select least(v1.r, v2.r) as min, greatest(v3.r, v4.r) as max
from v1
join v2
join v3
join v4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f015/1/1)**:

```
| min | max |
|-----|-----|
|   3 |  50 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select least(v1.r, v2.r) as min, greatest(v3.r, v4.r) as max
from 
(
  select min(s_min) as r
  from t
  where s_min >0
) as v1
join
(
  select min(s_max) as r
  from t
  where s_max >0
) as v2
join
(
  select max(s_min) as r
  from t
  where s_min >0
) as v3
join
(
  select max(s_max) as r
  from t
  where s_max >0
) as v4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f015/1/2)**:

```
| min | max |
|-----|-----|
|   3 |  50 |
```

Comment: похоже на правду, завтра проверю в системе

Comment: Есть предположение, что нужно выкидывать нули независимо, то есть два отдельных запроса для s_min и s_max

Comment: @andreymal, вообще-то `s_max >= 0` тут вообще не нужно: положительные числа обычно больше отрицательных. // убрал эту конструкцию.

Comment: ух, работа с псевдонимами пока непостигнутая мной фича SQL =\
   К тому же, насколько я понимаю, присвоение псевдонимов идет на этапе создания таблицы ?  а я в своем скрипте работаю уже с готовой.

Comment: вы учли, что там возвращается **два** значения в одной строке массива? к тому же первый из запросов, насколько я понял, вам не подходит.

Comment: да, конечно, я беру значения через fetch_row по индексам [0] и [1].  но я смог проверить только первый запрос, который, как вы сами заметили, не возвращает МАКС, если он лежит в первом столбце. Кроме этого, он вернул значения с 10 знаками после запятой, хотя в моей тбл попадаются с одной )  query2 и 3 я не знаю как в моем случае вписать в скрипт =\ а с query1 мой код примерно такой: `$query = "SELECT MIN(S_MIN) AS MIN, MAX(S_MAX) AS MAX FROM t WHERE ID = ".$id." AND S_MIN > 0;";  $result = mysql_query($query) or die();  $area = mysql_fetch_row($result);  $smin= $area[0];  $smax=$area[1];`

Comment: я не зря писал вопрос включая **php**-ую часть. мб решение по оптимизации лежит и там ?   ибо использование решений с view не выглядят уже сильно быстрее по сравнению с моим первоначальным рабочим скриптом с тремя запросами

Comment: третий запрос не требует предварительного создания *view*. запишите его как есть в одну строчку. // по поводу того, что оптимальней — три запроса или один, без «замеров на местности» судить невозможно. вы спрашивали, как три запроса заменить одним — я предложил несколько из возможных вариантов.

Comment: завтра тогда замерю на местности в phpmyadmin = )

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(if(s_min>0,s_min,NULL)) as smin,
       greatest(max(s_min),max(s_max)) as smax
  from `table`
```